# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to predict locality from the given address. I have saved model and loading by using python

```
locality_address= df_fatch_ID_Address['Col_1_add'].values.tolist()

print (locality_address)
```

after printing `locality_address` getting below type address but while running `result_locality` getting error.

Input Data:

```
Kastur Park
Green Homes, Kanti Nagar
Tata Shubh Griha, Vasind
```

I am getting error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'` after running below like.

```
result_locality = model_locality.predict(locality_address)
print (result_locality)
```

Comment: provide complete error message.

Comment: The error means that you are trying to set `lower` to a None value. So somewhere in your data there is probably a NaN-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all your data in `locality_address` are of the `str` type.
This means that `model_locality.predict(locality_address)` is calling a `str.lower()` function on the data and failing because some data are `None`.
To fix this, you have to clean your dataset to ensure that `None` is changed to `''` or some other value your `model_locality.predict()` can work with.